# MS visual studio 17 , ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-design

When opening a new project, i don't have the below option available to me

new project -->Web--> ASP.NET Core Web Application (.net framework)

Can you please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to install the right components with the Visual Studio Installer application. Are you on Windows? It shouldn't be too hard to install then. Just open the installer and look for anything having to do with web development and .NET.